# Segmentation bug and Ruby syntax clarification

Tags: ruby

I got an error with this code:

```
o = Hash.new do |h,k|
  h[k]
end
o[1] # => [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x007fff5f3fff80
```

---

Trying to understand what [this code](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz154.html) is doing:

```
optimal_change = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  hash[key] = if key < coins.min
    []
  elsif coins.include?(key)
    [key]
  ...
```

`o = Hash.new` and `hash` receive a block. What does `hash[key] = if key < coins.min` mean? Where is `key` getting it's value from? And what is this `= if` condition?

Comment: Please ask one question per thread. Your first part includes an import bug discovery, but your second part is gibberish. It is not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Sawa, it's all part of the same question.... I don't know how to ask it because I don't know what the code is.

Comment: Regarding the first point, I just made a bug report on [Ruby trunk](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9900).

Comment: Sawa ok that's cool. Do you think you can help me understand the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, your *IRB* crashed due to *never ending recursion*. You did

```
o = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] }
o[1]
```

Here, you are trying to access the value of key `1` of the hash which has been assigned to `o`. Now when you will be doing `o[1]`, you block will be called, inside the block you again did `h[1]`, it again calls the same block, the same is being repeated and it falls into never ending recursion, so the *error* comes out. But the error should be *stack level too deep (SystemStackError)*.

**NOTE**, `Hash::new` with the *block version*, *block will be called, only when you would do `hash[key]` and in the `hash`, `key` will not be present.*

But in the second case, you are assigning the value to the **key** of the hash object assgined to `o`, depending upon the same condition, if the **key** not already added to `O`, when you are doing `o[:key]`. Thus there will not be *infinite recursion*.

```
# result of the if-else block will be assigned to the **key** of the **hash**.
hash[key] = if key < coins.min # some condition check is being performed here.
              [] # then an empty is being assigined to the hash[key]
            elsif coins.include?(key) # again a condition test
              [key] # if true this value will be returned.
            else
               # some vale, which you didn't show us. If it is not present, and
               # no condition will be evaluated as true, there is a definite infinte
               # recursion will be happened again.
            end
```

Read this [`Hash::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-new) and [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`Hash#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) methods.

Example :-

```
coins = [10, 11, 45, 54]
o = Hash.new do |h,k|
  h[k] = if k < coins.min
            []
         elsif coins.include? k
           [k]
         else
            "k" # I don't know the actual need, this is just to show you
         end
end

o[5]
o # => {5=>[]}
o[11] # => [11]
o # => {5=>[], 11=>[11]}
o[88]
o  # => {5=>[], 11=>[11], 88=>"k"}
```

Comment: Hey Arup, I appreciate your answer, but I'm still having some issue comprehending this. Perhaps you know of some relevent specific links with solid examples I can review? Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting. But from the `Hash::new` doc's example. `h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Go Fish: #{key}" }` Why does this code not get into recursion?

Comment: I guess there hash[key] is rvalue. And even though that value is then returned, it's not returned by looking up the hash, again...?

Comment: Arup I will investigate further +1 please consider editing with an example of the execution flow. That would help me better understand the code. You can see the full code on the link in the question above.

Comment: @Spundun Remove *= "Go Fish: #{key}"* and see the magic... :-) Doc example is correct, as When you would do `hash[key]`, at that time, 2 things can be happened ( if you defined the hash with `:new` and *block*)- **a.** key exist in the hash. If so, that value will be returned, block will not be called. **b** key not exist, then block will be called, and the assign the vale to the key, by evaluating the *right side* expression.

Comment: @ArupRakshit You are right that there is an infinite recursion (hence there is a Ruby level error), but that should raise a stackoverflow error. The kind of error that was raised is Ruby's bug. Whenever you see a segmenation fault, it is either Ruby or some C-level library's bug.

Comment: Oh right, and now that the key exists in the hash, the block won't be called again for that hash.

Comment: @sawa Yes.. I mentioned it now, and forgot to write it there. But what you said about the *system level error*, I was not aware of. Thanks for letting me know the same.